# Fill gaps between vinyl floor

Tags: floor, gap, vinyl

I installed this "click" vinyl, but there's one corner of my floor(concrete) that's uneven, because of that the vinyl doesn't click properly and there's a small gap.

Can I just caulk this gap or do I have a better option here?

[image]

Comment: It's possible, POSSIBLE, a heat gun might soften the vinyl enough to make it click together.  You can test on scraps you may have.

Comment: I'm not the expert, but I'd think that fixing the underlying floor would be a far better solution than applying a band-aid on top.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying that you can't assemble the flooring panels because there's a hump in the concrete subfloor? Sure, you can caulk the gap, but it'll look like a caulked gap and not proper flooring. Maybe revise your post to ask about the actual problem rather than this symptom of it.

Comment: If it's a "bump" you may be able to grind it down.  Otherwise you'll need to level the entire surface.  Usually a flowable leveling product is used for this purpose but it's generally beyond the capabilities of a DIYer.